# Does anyone "DROP TABLE notes;" on Android Notepadv3 Tutorial?

Tags: android, notepad

I've just finished Notepadv# tutorials. And then, I connect through console(adb shell) the 'data' file Notepadv3 tutorial. I tried something.

1. Delete notes table, and re-run.

   - Do not work.
2. Delete data file(db file), and re-run.

   - Work.

If you worked Notepadv# tutorials, you may know about some pre-processing in NotesDbAdapter class. At that code position, I found "selecting db" on constructor, "creating table" on onCreate method and "update table" on onUpgrade method.

By that method, database(file named data) create table when onCreate called after constructor. No way, that didn't work. Above 2 like-moron test caused by that nonsense. Does anyone drop the notes table on console? I can't find why create doesn't work.

ps - So sorry about stupid English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your database onCreate method will only create the database if it does not exist. If it is corrupt (i.e. you've dropped the Notes table), or exists but is empty, then it is up to the application to detect that and recover.

This is why the notepad example fails when you drop the table (the database exists, so onCreate is not called and your database is corrupt), but when you delete the database it does work because onCreate is called and it recreates the database.

So basically, don't do that :-)

See the [SQLiteOpenHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html) documentation for a more detailed description.

Comment: Probably I have to see SQLiteOpenHelper's onCreate more detaily as you said. Thx a lot.

Comment: According to your advice, we must not access db just like my question. But if I call onCreate when constructor is called, I could get the solution. I added "IF NOT EXISTS" query in DATABASE_CREATE, and then, I called onCreate in constructor. It worked very well! Basically, I must not drop table via console when app is running, but I solve this moron question by above little working. Thx again all.

Comment: Absolutely correct - modifying the database outside of the app is potentially a bad idea. However, I would suggest it's better to let Android call your `onCreate()` when it needs to and to have a separate `checkDBIntegrity()` function which would fix up the schema if required. This will keep your `onCreate` simple and doing the job it is intended to do, and your app will be more maintainable because the program flow will be clear.

Comment: Thx again RivieraKid :-). Helpfulllll!

Answer (score 0):

Tried to uninstall the application or deleting the application data from Settings->manage application?

Comment: It's just same 2.Delete data file(db file), and re-run. isn't it?